# How to extract two fields into array Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Here is a table with two fields: startitime, endtime. I pull out data using:

```
ScheduleModel::all();
```

It returns me a data collection.
How to get result in plain array like this: `[starttime1, endtime1, starttime1, endtime2...]`

I have tried to use `pluck()` but it returns me an array with (key => value) instead plain array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scheduleVal = ScheduleModel::all();
$scheduleTime = array();

foreach ($scheduleVal as $schedule) {
    array_push($scheduleTime, $schedule->starttime, $schedule->endtime);
}

dd($scheduleTime);
```